# sql join problem with negatives

Tags: c#, sql, sqlclr

I need to select data from two table using a join. This is fairly simple and have no problems here. The problem occurs when the field I am joining is used as two separate foreign keys (I didn't design this). So the ID field that I join on is either a positive or negative number.

If it's a positive number it relates to ID_1 on the table_2 table, if it's a negative, the number relates to ID_2 on the table_2 table. However the ID_2 will be a positive number (even though it's stored as a negative in the foreign key). Obviously there are no constraints to enforce these - so in essence not real foreign keys :/

The SQL I'm using goes something like this and is fine for the positive numbers:

```
select t1.Stuff, t2.MoreStuff from table_1 t1
join table_2 t2 on t1.ID_1 = t2.ID_1
where ...
```

How to incorporate the negative aspect of this into the join. Is this even possible? Ideally I'd like to alter the table to my needs but apparently this is not a valid option. I'm well and truly stuck.

The only other idea I've had is a separate sql statement to handle these odd ones. This is all being run by clr sql from C#. Adding a separate SqlCommand to the code will most likely slow things down hence why I'd prefer to keep it all in one command.

Your input is welcome, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say the tables look like this:

```
Table1 (id INT, foo INT, fk INT)

Table2 (id1 INT, id2 INT, bar VARCHAR(100))
```

...where `fk` can be used to look up a row in `Table2` using `id1` if positive and `id2` if negative.

Then you can do the join as follows:

```
SELECT T1.id, T1.foo, T2.bar
FROM Table1 T1 INNER JOIN Table2 T2
ON    (T1.fk > 0 AND T2.id1 = T1.fk)
   OR (T1.fk < 0 AND T2.id2 = - T1.fk)
```

Comment: there is a rather long winded where clause so will avoid the union but thanks for the input. Loads of suggestions and I think I'll use yours Gary

Answer (score 2):

Simpliest way - join these tables using UNION ALL:

```
select t1.Stuff, t2.MoreStuff from table_1 t1
join table_2 t2 on t1.ID_1 = t2.ID_1
where t1._ID_1>0
UNION ALL
select t1.Stuff, t2.MoreStuff from table_1 t1
join table_2 t2 on abs(t1.ID_1) = t2.ID_2
where t1._ID_1<0
```

Comment: I upvoted this and Gary McGill's answer. Both should work. I would be interested to know if the UNION solution is faster or slower than the complex IN clause solution.

Comment: I assume you don't actually want ALL the rows in the table, in which case you'll need a WHERE clause. Which makes the UNION method a bit of a pain, since you'll need to duplicate the WHERE part.

Comment: Agreed with Gary, my solution is slower.

Answer (score 1):

This won't be very performant...but then, nothing will.  You need to transform your negative key into a positive one, and conditional logic for the join.  Like this:

```
select t1.Stuff, t2.MoreStuff 
from table_1 t1
join table_2 t2 on (t1.ID_1 > 0 AND t1.ID_1 = t2.ID_1)
  OR (t1.ID_1 <0 AND ABS(t1.ID_1) = t2.ID_2)
where ...
```

No chance of using an index, because you're transforming t1.ID_1 (with the ABS function), but it's the best that you can do given the circumstances.

Comment: What happened to the CASE statement? :-)

Comment: Hahaha...you caught me after posting, and before I realized that I didn't use a case statement at all ;-)

Revised now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, but only after introducing the schema designer to a LART:

```
SELECT
    t1.stuff, COALESCE(t2a.morestuff, t2b.morestuff)
  FROM
    table_1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table_2 t2a ON (t1.id_1 > 0 AND t1.id_1 = t2a.id_1)
    LEFT JOIN table_2 t2b ON (t1.id_1 < 0 AND t1.id_1 = -1 * t2b.id_2)
  // etc
```

Alternatively,

```
SELECT
    t1.stuff, t2.morestuff
  FROM
    table_1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON (
      (t1.id_1 > 0 AND t1.id_1 = t2.id_1)
      OR (t1.id_1 < 0 AND t1.id_1 = -1 * t2.id_2)
    )
  // etc
```

Remember the LART, that's the most important part!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        ID INT,
        ForeignKeyID INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table (ID,ForeignKeyID) SELECT 1, 1
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,ForeignKeyID) SELECT 2, 2
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,ForeignKeyID) SELECT 3, -1
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,ForeignKeyID) SELECT 4, -2

DECLARE @ForeignTable TABLE(
        ID_1 INT,
        ID_2 INT,
        Val VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @ForeignTable (ID_1,ID_2,Val) SELECT 1, 11, '1'
INSERT INTO @ForeignTable (ID_1,ID_2,Val) SELECT 2, 22, '2'
INSERT INTO @ForeignTable (ID_1,ID_2,Val) SELECT 3, 1, '3'
INSERT INTO @ForeignTable (ID_1,ID_2,Val) SELECT 3, 2, '4'

SELECT  *
FROM    @Table t INNER JOIN
        @ForeignTable ft ON ABS(t.ForeignKeyID) =
                            CASE 
                                WHEN t.ForeignKeyID > 0
                                    THEN ft.ID_1
                                ELSE
                                    ft.ID_2
                            END
```

Answer (score 0):

It will have to be something like

```
select t1.Stuff, t2.MoreStuff from table_1 t1, table_2 t2 where (t1.ID_1 = t2.ID_1 OR t1.ID_1 = CONCAT("-",t2.ID_1)) where ...
```

Not sure if I have misunderstood your question.

Comment: What makes you think that the ID fields are text?

Answer (score 0):

By applying left joins across table two and using the absolute value function, you should be able to accomplish what you're looking for:

```
SELECT t1.Stuff, isnull(t2.MoreStuff, t2_2.MoreStuff) 
FROM table_1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table_2 t2     ON t1.ID_1 = t2.ID_1 
                             AND t1.ID_1 > 0
    LEFT JOIN table_2 t2_2   ON abs(t1.ID_2) = t2_2.ID_2 
                             AND t1.ID_2 < 0
WHERE 
   ...
```

The caveat here is that if `ID_1` and `ID_2` are not mutually exclusive you will get 2 query results.

Comment: Pretty sure this won't work. Can't alias two tables with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.Stuff, t2.MoreStuff from table_1 t1
join table_2 t2 on t1.ID_1 = t2.ID_1 or -t1.ID_1 = t2.ID_2
where ...
```